# PHP Read Text File With Following Labels

Tags: php, function, readfile

So I have these text file which contains some details on it and I would like PHP to extract and distribute each of the data individually.

Example Data on the text file :

```
Plugin Name: Sample Framework
Description: This is a sample framework
Author: User Friendly
```

What I wanted is to get each data from the specific labels, like if I want to get the "Plugin Name", so the expected result would be:

```
Sample Framework
```

And if I want to get the Description that would be :

```
This is a sample framework
```

But I don't know how to do it. The preg_replace or preg_match might work however if there's a rumble data on the text file I don't think that will works but I am open to any answers.

I have also this existing function to determine what kind of details I want to display.

See example below:

```
<?php
function getDetails($var){
    if($var=='pname'){
        //get the plugin name
    }
} ?>
```

I think there are many platforms can do that but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Will your file only contain these 3 lines or will you have multiple of the same line?

Comment: I think it could be possible that user can add more lines but as for now, those on the lists are the major ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just read your file into an array with `file()` and then extract the first row as keys and the other as data, which you then can `array_combine()` together.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $lines = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(":", $v);
    }, $lines);

    $data = array_combine(array_map("array_shift", $lines), array_map("array_pop", $lines));

    print_r($data);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Plugin Name] =>  Sample Framework
    [Description] =>  This is a sample framework
    [Author] =>  User Friendly
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was so impressive.
Instead of using print_r($data); I could also add a parameter to select the specific data in array print_r($data['Author']);